# Javascript: function declaration type important for setInterval and onComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

My question is basically an extension to this one:
[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1714755).
I've read through all the answers, but I think I'm still missing the answer to this question:

Why does the type of function declaration matter for jQuery's onComplete event and the native setInterval method? Moreover, why does it matter for these, but not for the normal addEventListener?

Example with onComplete events (assuming `blinkOn()` is called):

```
//like this the onComplete event works normally and the functions call eachother
function blinkOn() { $blink.fadeIn( 500, blinkOff ); }
function blinkOff() { $blink.fadeOut( 500, blinkOn ); }

//like this blinkOff won't be called after the fadeIn
function blinkOn() { $blink.fadeIn( 500, blinkOff ); }
var blinkOff = function() { $blink.fadeOut( 500, blinkOn ); };
```

Example with setInterval:

```
//works fine
var timer = setInterval( onTimer, 700);
function onTimer() { ... }

//won't work
var timer = setInterval( onTimer, 700);
var onTimer = function() { ... }
```

The reason I'd like to know is because I want consistency in my code. If the only way to get that is just using `function a() { ... }`, that's okay. But I think `var a = function() { ... }` is more clear in defining scope. And I'm just really curious.

Comment: Have you defined the `var onTimer` function within another function, or is it in the global scope?

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery, native addEventListener or setInterval - all work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to define your function above where your calls to the function are, you'd have no issues.

var toggleLight = function () { light = !light; };

setInterval(toggleLight, 500);

Your problem is that you're trying to access things which don't exist yet.

It's the exact same thing as trying to do this:

```
var c = a + b,

    a = 12,
    b = 3;
```

When the program hits `c`, `a` and `b` don't exist.

Think of this as happening in three steps, for every single function:

```
var a = 12,
    b = 3,
    c = add(a, b);

function add (a, b) { return a + b; }
```

**STEP 1.**
The engine grabs the named function `add` and works out what it does (defines all named-functions first).

**STEP 2.**
The engine locates all variables in the function and sets them to `undefined`:

```
var a = undefined,
    b = undefined,
    c = undefined;

function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

**STEP 3.**
The engine initializes all variables in order.

```
// 3.1
var a = 12,
    b = undefined,
    c = undefined;


// 3.2
var a = 12,
    b = 3,
    c = undefined;

// 3.3
var a = 12,
    b = 3,
    c = add(a, b); // = return a + b = 15
```

So doing something like this:

```
callFunction(myFunc);
var myFunc = function () {};
```

Is equal to this:

```
var myFunc = undefined;
callFunction(myFunc);
myFunc = function () {};
```

**Solution:**

Separate your implementation from your action.
Make sure everything is defined before you call anything.

Comment: Aah thanks I see clearly now! It had me so tangled why a difference in function-declaration could cause this. I just thought the named function was a shorthand (doing exactly the same) as the other. But it makes total sense as you describe it. The cases where it did and did not work in my code all had to do with the order.

Comment: It's not a shorthand.  You can even name functions which are assigned to vars:  `var myFunc = function yourFunc (param) { doStuff(param); };` And that's useful for things like recursion (it can call itself by function-name, instead of variable name, in the function). BUT not even this will get past the `undefined` aspect, and you can't use the function name, either (only declared functions work like that - meaning even if its named, it can't be on the right of an `=`). One thing to keep in mind, though -- if you call a function inside of another function's body, it doesn't need to be defined

Comment: until you call it.  Here's what I mean: `var func2 = function (data) { func1(data), func1 = function (data) { doStuff(data); };`. In this case `func2` knows about `func1`, and like I said, when `func2` is created, `func1` is still `undefined`. But it doesn't need to be defined until `func2` is called, because that variable resolution happens at the last second, when a function gets called. The difference between this working and the problem you had was that you were passing `undefined` into other functions (like `setTimeout`). You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks again! All very useful stuff to know!

Answer (score 1):

Named functions are kinda created in the nowhere, so they become globally available in the scope where they are defined, where as anonymous functions assigned to an identifier are only available once the identifier they are bound to is defined.

So what you are running into there is a simple race condition problem. Your first non-working example should work in case `blinkOn()` is called after the `blikOff` variable definition.

Your second non-working example doesn't work because `onTimer` is not yet defined when `setInterval` is invoked. Move the variable definition before the `setInterval` call and it will work.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first non-technical circumscription of what's going on there that came to my mind :)

Comment: Haha it does capture the spirit. But now I think more of sticking to named functions. It is appealing to separate all logic from the actions.. but I see no harm in functions that are globally available in their own scope? Just being able to call them anywhere in their own scope seems more like an advantage, or not?

Comment: Well, i don't know how all the different engines handle that internally, but there's probabyl little to no difference, other than that a named function is being declared as the first thing in the the scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
//like this blinkOff won't be called after the fadeIn
function blinkOn() { $blink.fadeIn( 500, blinkOff ); }
var blinkOff = function() { $blink.fadeOut( 500, blinkOn ); };
```

It will be called. You just have to make sure that `blinkOn` is not *called* (referenced is okay) before (above) the assignment.